# How to perform sort in array of objects in one record in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I want to fetch the data by sorting xm_score but it's not working with my query.

```
  query = match.find({ '_id': 'k00012' }).sort('npi.xm_score');
```

I need to get the objects in npi get sorted by xm_score in this array.

I have the data as follows,

```
{
 "term":'k00012',
 "npi" : [ 
    {
        "npi" : "1003000126",
        "xm_score" : 77.1,
        "geo" : [ 
            -75.53091147, 
            40.60619643
        ],
        "state" : "PA",
        "zip" : "18103",
        "specialty" : [ 
            "x010"
        ]
    },
    {
        "npi" : "1003000126",
        "xm_score" : 70.1,
        "geo" : [ 
            -75.53091147, 
            40.60619643
        ],
        "state" : "PA",
        "zip" : "18103",
        "specialty" : [ 
            "x010"
        ]
    }] 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have a custom function for sorting array

```js
let obj = {
 "term":'k00012',
 "npi" : [ 
    {
        "npi" : "1003000126",
        "xm_score" : 77.1,
        "geo" : [ 
            -75.53091147, 
            40.60619643
        ],
        "state" : "PA",
        "zip" : "18103",
        "specialty" : [ 
            "x010"
        ]
    },
    {
        "npi" : "1003000126",
        "xm_score" : 70.1,
        "geo" : [ 
            -75.53091147, 
            40.60619643
        ],
        "state" : "PA",
        "zip" : "18103",
        "specialty" : [ 
            "x010"
        ]
    }] 
 }
 
let arr = obj.npi;

arr.sort((a,b) => {
  return a.xm_score - b.xm_score
})

console.log(arr)
```